# prototype selector equivalent to jQuery

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, selector

How can I select the *popupwindow* of the *popup-lightbox* div?

in jQuery, it's be something like $('div#popup-lightbox #popupwindow'). Unfortunatly, in Prototype, it's not that easy... anyone can help me? thanks!

```
<div id="popup-lightbox" class="popup">
    <div id="popupoverlay"></div>
    <div id="popupdiv">
        <div id="popupwindow"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="popup-modal" class="popup">
    <div id="popupoverlay"></div>
    <div id="modaldiv">
        <div id="popupwindow">
            <div id="modalint">Your changes have not been saved.</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, you're using ID attributes incorrectly.  According to the W3C specification, ID attributes are supposed to be unique across the document.

That aside, the prototype selection syntax is slightly different from jQuery:

```
$("popup-lightbox").select("#popupwindow")[0];
```

Comment: for some reason, I have duplicated IDs on the page. I am trying to make them unique, but I have to get this one working.
what you provided works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the bling-bling http://api.prototypejs.org/language/dollardollar/

`$$('#popup_lightbox #popup_window')` (also, you are not using ids properly, like desau and fantactuka said)

Answer (score 1):

Actually since id should be uniq at the page I'm not sure that it makes sense to use complex selector. Why not just $('popupwindow')?